# Removing multiple objects from a list according to some criteria

Tags: c#

I came across some code at one point that was trying to remove objects from a list that met a certain criteria.

There was a list of said objects that was already created with some stuff in it:

```
List<Foo> FooList = new List<Foo>()
FooList.Add(...)
FooList.Add(...)
```

In some other function, they then went off to remove some objects:

```
List<Foo> RemovedFoo = new List<Foo>()
foreach (Foo f in FooList
    if (f.Condition)
        RemoveFoo.Add(f);

foreach (Foo f in RemovedFoo)
    FooList.Remove(f);

RemovedFoo.Clear();
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I understand that you can't simply do the remove in the first loop, but surely there must be a smarter way to do this.

Comment: i may be missing something but all the answers seem equiv. to what you say you can't do, which is do the remove in the first loop - the extension method just hides the loop from you, right?

Comment: Yes, and it also seems to duplicate something that I didn't even see before. This was in some real code before (I didn't write it). I forgot to check the MSDN documentation to see if List had something like this at the time.

Comment: You can remove items from the list if you use a for loop. You can't remove items from the list if you use a foreach loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
FooList.RemoveAll(f => f.Condition);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FooList.RemoveAll(ele => ele.Condition);
```

Note that this is specific to `List<T>`.

if you had a general collection, you could use LINQ:

```
var newCollection = FooList.Where(ele => !ele.Condition);
```

Comment: The second example is not the same thing. The first one mutates a list, the second filters a collection.

Comment: I would hope that's apparent since in the first snippet I treat it as though it's in-place and in the second I assign the result to a new collection.

Answer (score -2):

Try an extension method...

```
public static class CollectionHelpers {
  public static void RemoveWhere<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, bool> selector) {
    var elementsToRemove = list.Where(expression).ToList();
    foreach (var element in list) {
      list.Remove(element);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure - as I now see - there are better answers. But mine isn't wrong or inaccurate. Why the downvote?

Comment: Most likely because it's reinventing the wheel. No need to create an extension method if the functionality already exists in List.

Comment: (not my downvote) Possible reasons: 1) this is not helpful because it already exists in List<T> 2) this does not compile (why the hell are you using an expression tree?) 3) this does not avoid the nuissance of having to create a separate list with the soon to be removed elements.

Comment: This doesn't work.You're removing all the items from the list because your `foreach` is looping over `list` instead of `elementsToRemove`.  (This will be obvious immediately, since it will throw `InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` during the loop.)